# Navbar que este en todas las pantallas Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, navbar, aplicación-movil, screen

estoy tratando de hacer un navbar, he probado diferentes librerías pero me he quedado con `persisten_nav_bar`, sin embargo no es tan persistente, en algunas pantallas no llega el navbar. Necesito ayuda para crear una navbar que tenga 4 iconos y un floatingActionButton, en el centro y que este menú, se mantenga o como lo puedo mantener en todas las pantallas, literalmente en todas, que me sugieren que haga?

Código:

```
      body: child,
      bottomNavigationBar: PersistentTabView(
        
        popAllScreensOnTapAnyTabs: true,
        navBarHeight: getSize(60),
        context,
        controller: _controller,
        screens: screen(),
        items: navBarItems(),
        confineInSafeArea: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white, // Default is Colors.white.
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset:
            true, // This needs to be true if you want to move up the screen when keyboard appears. Default is true.
        hideNavigationBarWhenKeyboardShows:
            true, // Recommended to set 'resizeToAvoidBottomInset' as true while using this argument. Default is true.
        decoration: NavBarDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            width: 2,
            color: ColorConstant.gray200,
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
          colorBehindNavBar: Colors.white,
        ),
        itemAnimationProperties: const ItemAnimationProperties(
          // Navigation Bar's items animation properties.
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
          curve: Curves.ease,
        ),
        screenTransitionAnimation: const ScreenTransitionAnimation(
          // Screen transition animation on change of selected tab.

          animateTabTransition: true,
          curve: Curves.easeInOut,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
        ),
        navBarStyle:
            NavBarStyle.style15, // Choose the nav bar style with this property.
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Como puedo usar este navbar en todas las pantallas o como puedo implementar un navbar reutilizable

Comment: Depende del gestor de estados que uses puede ser el modo de implementar una vista global y de allí colocar una sub-vistas, las vista global es la que debe tener el bottom-bar.

Comment: Puedes hacer algo asi: [Nested Navigation Flutter](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/nested-nav)